# C# ListViewItems is not returning empty

Tags: c#, winforms, listviewitem

I am using this method and it keeps saying listView1 has items even though none appear in the listview?

```
        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\test.txt";
        if (Directory.Exists(filePath))
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (TextReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] data = line.Split(new char[] { ',' });
                        ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();

                        if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("ListViewCount#1: '" + listView1.Items.Count + "'.");
                        }

                        lvi.Text = data[0];
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(data[1]);
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(data[3]);
                        lvi.SubItems.Add(data[4]);
                        lvi.Tag = data[2];

                        listView1.Items.Add(lvi);

                        if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("ListViewCount#2: '" + listView1.Items.Count + "'.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (listView1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: ListView has no data to show.");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

The listView1.count is more than 0 after the "lvi" part, prior to that it is empty(tested with messagebox counting listView1 before and after this method), why is it saying it has a "listView1.count of 1" if all the "data" is empty? I have tried other ways to work around this using custom booleans in other methods but its just not practical referring back to them, all i want to do is if listview1 is 0 tell user there is no data.

Comment: What is the input for your `StreamReader`? Is it possible that the input is a file with only a newline character?

Comment: Can you please add missing code? Where is `listView1` instantiated?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Also such questions need [MCVE]

Comment: Your `listView1`  will contains data if `(line = sr.ReadLine()) != null` is `true` or if it already contains some data before this code. But you didn't show us full code :(

Comment: @kat1330 I updated my method for you to see, this is NOT the exact method i am using, my file path is much better(using a savefiledialog etc) few other things but i have simplified it to be simple but basically that is what I am doing. I also added the listviewItem1.count  message box events so you can see I am trying, and the first count at run time is 0, the second is reading 1.

Answer (score 0):

You must have initialised you listview earlier in the code so as to not get a runtime error at:

```
listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
```

The instantiation of the listview will create an empty listview with a count of 0 thus passing your if declaration.